# .load page within linked javascript and css files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, load

Description:
I have a main page with header, footer, etc. The content (a div within body) of this page is changing depending on where you click(menu items). The content loaded are different pages within javascript and css files.

Problem: javascript and css files of the pages loaded don't work. I have to include ALL the page in order to make it works.

For example in the next code, javascript included in status.jsp don't work:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){
    // status.jsp has javascript and css linked
    $("#content").load("pages/status.jsp #information");
}
```

However, this works, but it is not what i want:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){
    // status.jsp has javascript and css linked
    $("#content").load("pages/status.jsp");
}
```

The result of the last code is a page similar to this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<title>MainPage</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css">
        <title>Status</title>
        <div id=statusBox">
            information
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/status.js"></script>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a space in `pages/status.jsp #information`.  That is, it should be `pages/status.jsp#information`.  But beyond that, the `#` only tells the browser to queue up to that point; it still loads all of the HTML.

Comment: @SableFoste uoh, thanks a lot, it works! It's just I am looking for. So http://api.jquery.com/load/ is confusing because it does a space.